# How much can buffs and debuffs stack?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In Guild Wars 2, when casting an existing buff (boon) or debuff (condition), rather than overwriting the current buff (or debuff), it will apply it's own separate effect.  The wiki explains that these effects will stack with previous applications, either by stacking the intensity (ie. Casting the same [Might](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Might) spell twice will double the effect), or the duration.

The [wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Effect_stacking) explains how boons stack in intensity.

Is there an upper limit to the intensity (either by number of stacks, or total effect) to any buffs or debuffs?

Comment: Hi, Patrick.  I've modified your question to hopefully be clearer, and grouped debuffs into it as well.  If you feel I've changed your question too much, feel free to roll it back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All intensity stacking effects (Might, Bleeding, Confusion, and Vulnerability) stack to a max of 25 times. Each stack has it's own internal duration.

All duration stacking effects (Fury, Protection, Regeneration, Retaliation, Swiftness, Vigor, Burning, Chilled, Crippled, Immobilized, Poison, Weakness, Stability) seem to have a max time limit of 22-24 hours. (The Guardian Virtue of Courage passive provides a 24 hour Aegis when it ticks.) The entire duration has the intensity of the best intensity applied to the stack.

Quickness is not a boon, but instances of Quickness do stack duration with each other as well.

Comment: This also counts for runes which apply 'boon' bonuses, such as the rune which gives you precision on each kill, it will max at 25 stacks.

Comment: Sounds like a good answer, but could you please tell me how/where you gathered the information?

Comment: @PatrickStalder (1) [Offical wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Effect_stacking), (2) I have played a Guardian with boon duration, I can get a 3 minute Swiftness stack pretty easily, also the 24 hour Aegis, (3) fought Champion Eye of Zaitain, who gives himself 25 stacks of buffs and a Retaliation buff that lasts forever, (4) Fighting champion monsters, players almost always apply 25 stacks of some condition.

Comment: How does this work with conditions with `intensity stack` and traits to `increase condition duration`? Does it increase the duration of each stack? Primarily Ranger 'Marksmanship' & 'Sharpened Edges' or 'Sharpening Stone'

Comment: @DavidYell Each stack of intensity has it's own internal timer. Example: I apply a 50 power burning for 5 seconds, and you apply a 10 power burning for 10 seconds. For 5 seconds, the stack shows a 2 icon and deals 50 power burning damage. Then for the remainder 5 seconds, the stack shows no number on the icon (1 stack) and deals 10 power burning damage.