# In Intensity stacking conditions

Tags: guild-wars-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much can buffs and debuffs stack?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82633/how-much-can-buffs-and-debuffs-stack)

Recently was asked about in Intensity stacking boons, but as a thief, I don't care about boons, I care about conditions.

Now my question is, how high can a condition stack, like Vulnerability?

As I'm pretty sure it's another thing with conditions than it is with boons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Guild Wars 2 wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Condition), conditions either [stack](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Effect_stacking) in intensity ( [Bleeding](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Bleeding), etc) or in duration ([Burning](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Burning), etc). Bleeding and Vulnerability both stack to 25.

Comment: Thanks, but where do you get the information about the stack height?